# How can i optimize this problem while using only 3 for loops?

Tags: c#, for-loop, optimization

So the problem that I'm trying to optimize is to find and print all four-digit numbers of the type ABCD for which: A + B = C + D.

For example:
1001
1010
1102
etc.

I have used four for loops to solve this (one for every digit of the number).

```
for (int a = 1; a <= 9; a++)
{
  for (int b = 0; b <= 9; b++)
  {
    for (int c = 0; c <= 9; c++)
    {
      for (int d = 0; d <= 9; d++)
      {
        if ((a + b) == (c + d))
        {
          Console.WriteLine(" " + a + " " + b + " " + c + " " + d);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My question is: how can I solve this using only 3 for loops?

Comment: Seems like you could do it with 2 loops from 10 to 99 and 0 to 99 and check if adding the digits of each equal.  Why are you looking to do it in 3?

Comment: Can it not just be done with 1?

Comment: @juharr Because... I'm dumb, I guess. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an option with **two** loops (though still 10,000 iterations), separating the pairs of digits:

```
int sumDigits(int input)
{
    int result = 0;
    while (input != 0)
    {
        result += input % 10;
        input /= 10;
    }
    return result;
}

//optimized for max of two digits
int sumDigitsAlt(int input)
{
    return (input % 10) + ( (input / 10) % 10);
}

// a and b
for (int i = 0; i <= 99; i++)
{
    int sum = sumDigits(i);

    // c and d
    for (int j = 0; j <= 99; j++)
    {
        if (sum == sumDigits(j))
        {
            Console.WriteLine( (100 * i) + j);
        }
    }
}
```

I suppose the `while()` loop inside of `sumDigits()` might count as a third loop, but since we know we have at most two digits we could remove it if needed.

And, of course, we can use a similar tactic to do this with **one** loop which counts from 0 to 9999, and even that we can hide:

```
var numbers = Enumerable.Range(0, 10000).
     Where(n => {
         // there is no a/b
         if (n < 100 && n == 0) return true;
         if (n < 100) return false;

         int sumCD = n % 10;
         n /= 10;
         sumCD += n % 10;
         n /= 10;

         int sumAB = n % 10;
         n /= 10;
         sumAB += n % 10;

         return (sumAB == sumCD);
     });
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to write a method that takes in an integer and returns `true` if  the integer is four digits and the sum of the first two equal the sum of the second two:

```
public static bool FirstTwoEqualLastTwo(int input)
{
    if (input < 1000 || input > 9999) return false;

    var first = input / 1000;
    var second = (input - first * 1000) / 100;
    var third = (input - first * 1000 - second * 100) / 10;
    var fourth = input - first * 1000 - second * 100 - third * 10;

    return (first + second) == (third + fourth);
}
```

Then you can write a single loop from 1000-9999 and output the numbers for which this is true with a space between each digit (not sure why that's the output, but it appears that's what you were doing in your sample code):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    for (int i = 1000; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        if (FirstTwoEqualLastTwo(i))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" " + string.Join(" ", i.ToString().ToArray()));
        }
    }

    Console.Write("Done. Press any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can compute the value of `d` from the values of `a,b,c`.

```
for (int a = 1; a <= 9; a++)
{
  for (int b = 0; b <= 9; b++)
  {
    for (int c = 0; c <= 9; c++)
    {
      if (a + b >= c && a + b <= 9 + c) 
      {
        int d = a + b - c;
        Console.WriteLine(" " + a + " " + b + " " + c + " " + d);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

We can further optimize by changing the condition of the third loop to `for (int c = max(0, a + b - 9); c <= a + b; c++)` and getting rid of the `if` statement.

Comment: a=9; b=9; c=0; would result in d = 18 which is outside of the "digit" range.  What you really want is `a + b - c > 0 && a + b - c < 10`

Comment: @juharr Thanks. That was rather silly of me.

Comment: Really the best thing would be to calculate `d` and then check if it's in the 1-9 range.